# Asynchronously receiving a file uploaded via ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm using a [jquery file uploader](https://github.com/jfeldstein/jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js), which is damn simple to use.

Basically, what it does is, it creates an `<iframe>` and adds a `<form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="settings.action">`

And then, it creates a `<input type="file">` inside that form and submits the form to the given `action` setting.

```
$('#sampleFile').ajaxfileupload({
  action:'AsyncFileUploadHandler.ashx' // submits the file to this url
});
```

And this is my handler:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="AsyncFileUploadHandler" %>
using System;
using System.Web;
public class AsyncFileUploadHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
        // I don't know how to grap the uploaded file here.
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I've seen MVC examples but not Web Forms. Googling really gave me nothing. And it seems that there is no duplicate of this question on SO.

### So, what should I do in my handler to get the file contents?

Answer (score 0):

I added name attribute to the file control and just `context.Request.Files[0]` and it worked correctly.